# zend search lucene

Tags: zend-framework, search, lucene, document

I have a database that I would like to leverage with `Zend_Search_Lucene`. However, I am having difficulty creating a "fully searchable" document for Lucene.

Each `Zend_Search_Lucene` document pulls information from two relational database tables (`Table_One` and `Table_Two`). `Table_One` has basic information (`id`, `owner_id`, `title`, `description`, `location`, etc.), `Table_Two` has a 1:N relationship to `Table_One` (meaning, for each entry in `Table_One`, there could be one or more entries in `Table_Two`). Table_Two contains: id, `listing_id`, `bedrooms`, `bathrooms`, `price_min`, `price_max`, `date_available`. See Figure 1.

Figure 1

```
Table_One
    id (Primary Key)
    owner_id
    title
    description
    location
    etc...

Table_Two
    id (Primary Key)
    listing_id (Foreign Key to Table_One)
    bedrooms (int)
    bathrooms (int)
    price_min (int)
    price_max (int)
    date_available (datetime)
```

The problem is, there are multiple `Table_Two` entries for each `Table_One` entry. [Question 1] How to create a `Zend_Search_Lucene` document where each field is unique? (See Figure 2)

Figure 2

```
Lucene Document
    id:Keyword
    owner_id:Keyword
    title:UnStored
    description:UnStored
    location: UnStored
    date_registered:Keyword
    ... (other Table_One information)
    bedrooms: UnStored
    bathrooms: UnStored
    price_min: UnStored
    price_max: UnStored
    date_available: Keyword
    bedrooms_1: <- Would prefer not to have do this as this makes the bedrooms harder to search.
```

Next, I need to be able to do a Range Query on the `bedrooms`, `bathrooms`, `price_min` and `price_max` fields. (Example: finding documents that have between 1 and 3 bedrooms) `Zend_Search_Lucene` will only allow ranged searches on the same field. From my understanding, this means each field I want to do a ranged query on can only contain one value (example: bedrooms:"1 bedroom");

What I have now, within the Lucene Document is the `bedrooms`, `bathrooms`, `price_min`, `price_max`, `date_available` fields being space delimited.

Example:

```
Sample Table_One Entry: 
    | 5 | 2 | "Sample Title" | "Sample Description" | "Sample Location" | 2008-01-12

Sample Table_Two Entries:
    | 10 | 5 | 3 | 1 | 900 | 1000 | 2009-10-01
    | 11 | 5 | 2 | 1 | 800 | 850 | 2009-08-11
    | 12 | 5 | 1 | 1 | 650 | 650 | 2009-09-15
```

Sample Lucene Document

```
id:5
owner_id:2
title: "Sample Title"
description: "Sample Description"
location: "Sample Location"
date_registered: [datetime stamp YYYY-MM-DD]
bedrooms: "3 bedroom 2 bedroom 1 bedroom" 
bathrooms: "1 bathroom 1 bathroom 1 bathroom"
price_min: "900 800 650"
price_max: "1000 850 650"
date_available: "2009-10-01 2009-08-11 2009-09-15"
```

[Question 2] Can you do a Range Query search on the `bedroom`, `bathroom`, `price_min`, `price_max`, `date_available` fields as they are shown above or does each range query field have to contain only one value (e.g. "1 bedroom")? I have not been able to get the Range Query to work in its current form. I am at a lose here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I suggest you create a separate Lucene document for each entry in Table_Two. This will cause some duplication of the Table_One information common to these entries, but this is not a high price to pay for much easier index structure in Lucene.
2. Use a [boolean query](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.query-api.html#zend.search.lucene.queries.boolean-query) to combine several [range queries](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.query-language.html#zend.search.lucene.query-language.range). The number-valued fields should be something like this:

`bedrooms: 3`

`price_min: 900`

and a sample query in Lucene syntax will be:

```
date_available:[20100101 TO 20100301] AND price_min:[600 TO 1000]
```